# I want to create nested JSON for following array using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to create nested JSON for using following array and it is separated according:

Array which is used to create JSON:

```
[
  'TC0159 - 24 Ghanta', (channel name which is starts from TC)
  '12PM-1659PM        (timeslot)                                                                519.00',              (rate)
  '5PM-2259PM                                                                        714.00',
  '6AM-1159AM                                                                        323.00',
  'TC0514 - 4 real news',
  '12PM-1659PM                                                                        128.00',
  '5PM-2259PM                                                                        128.00',
  '6AM-1159AM                                                                        128.00',
  'TC0227 - 9 X M',
  '10PM-10:30PM                                                                        1105.00',
  '12PM-7PM                                                                        1105.00',
  '7AM-9AM                                                                        1496.00',
  '7PM-8PM                                                                        1105.00',
  '8PM-10PM                                                                        1105.00',
  '9AM-12PM                                                                        1887.00',
  'TC0224 - 9X',
  '10PM-10:30PM                                                                        128.00',
  '12PM-7PM                                                                        323.00',
  '7AM-9AM                                                                        128.00',
  '7PM-8PM                                                                        323.00',
  '8PM-10PM                                                                        128.00',
  '9AM-12PM                                                                        128.00'
]
```

I want to make JSON as represented below using the above array.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "channel_name": "channelName",
        "timeslot": {
            "10:00-1:00": 600,
            "2:00-5:00": 800
        }
    },
    {
        "channel_name": "channelName",
        "timeslot": {
            "10:00-1:00": 600,
            "2:00-5:00": 800
        }
    },
    {
        "channel_name": "channelName",
        "timeslot": {
            "10:00-1:00": 600,
            "2:00-5:00": 800
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: "sing the above array" - I'm not good at singing. :/ Anyway I don't understand your question. Where do the numbers after the timeslots come from. And how are you creating the array in the first place. Where's your code? What did you try?

Comment: timeslots represents the key and rate represents its value